# SetChecked RadioButton of SingleChoice ListView on Activity Launch

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I've been working on creating a single choice ListView populated by a custom ArrayAdapter (which works), except I need to set a pre-determined RadioButton in the ListView as `setChecked(true)` when the activity launches.

I'm populating my ListView with a `List<Server>` servers object at inflation that contains a boolean 'default_server' used to determine which row / RadioButton should be `setChecked(true)`.

Selecting the various ListView items after the activity has launched correctly flags the specific RadioButton as `setChecked(true)` in Single Choice mode as desired.

My code:

**ServerActivity.java**

```
public class ServersActivity extends FragmentActivity
//FragmentActivity needed to display dialog fragment when ListView item clicked
...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.server_list);
    servers = getServers();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    adapter = new ServerActivityArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.server_list_item, servers);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // show dialog if not long clicked
            if (!longClicked) {
                lv.setItemChecked(position, true);
                showServerDialog(position);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**ServerActivityArrayAdapter.java**

```
public class ServerActivityArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Server> {

private int layout;
private int mSelectedPosition = -1;
private RadioButton mSelectedRB;

private static LayoutInflater inflater;

public ServerActivityArrayAdapter(Context context, int layout, List<Server> servers) {
    super(context, layout, servers);
    ListArrays listArrays = new ListArrays(context);
    this.layout = layout;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

private static class ServerViewHolder {
    private TextView textView;
    private RadioButton radioButton;

    public ServerViewHolder() {
        // EMPTY DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Server server = this.getItem(position);
    final ServerViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ServerViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvServerName);
        viewHolder.radioButton = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbDefault);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ServerViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // TODO: SET THE DEFAULT SERVER

    viewHolder.radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (position != mSelectedPosition && mSelectedRB != null) {
                mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
            }
            mSelectedPosition = position;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            mSelectedRB = (RadioButton) v;
            server.setDefaultServer(mSelectedRB.isChecked());
        }
    });

    if (mSelectedPosition != position) {
        viewHolder.radioButton.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        viewHolder.radioButton.setChecked(true);
        if (mSelectedRB != null && viewHolder.radioButton != mSelectedRB) {
            mSelectedRB = viewHolder.radioButton;
        }
    }

    viewHolder.textView.setText(server.getName());
    return convertView;
    }
}
```

Again, my `List<Server>` servers object is populating the ListView, the subsequent dialog popups (when a row is clicked) correctly and the RadioButtons on each row are currently functioning in Single Choice mode. I'm using `server.setDefaultServer(mSelectedRB.isChecked());` in the setOnClickListener of ServerActivityArrayAdapter to update which server has `default_server(true)`.

Everything I've tried so far in the ServerActivityArrayAdapter seems to break the Single Choice mode requirement of the RadioButton. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did go back and implement Shared Preferences into my project as Mridul suggested, but the solution really didn't require them.

Basically, I updated the constructor of my ServerActivityArrayAdapter class to let me pass the ID of the default server from the ServerActivity class when it's created.  Also, I set mSelectionPostion = defServer, so the correct RadioButton in my ListView is checked when everything is inflated.

```
public ServerActivityArrayAdapter(Context context, int layout, List<Server> servers, int defServer) {
    super(context, layout, servers);
    ListArrays listArrays = new ListArrays(context);
    this.layout = layout;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mSelectedPosition = defServer;
}
```